# Problem with displaying images in MVC with a virtual directory configured

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, routes, razor

I have a MVC application hosted on a IIS 7.5
In my project I have a local images folder in a different location that is configured in IIS as a virtual directory say /otherimages

When I try to reference this path from the view it doesn't display the images, images that are hosted in /Content folder work perfectly, how can I configure this to work.

I tried

```
Url.Content("~/otherimages/pic.jpg")
```

but plain img tag doesn't work either.

Thank you

Comment: Can you browse to this image if you just follow the link through a web browser?

Comment: I solved the problem It was permission issues, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should work. i would check permissions. Go have a look at the IIS logs to see if you get a response other than 200 status.

Comment: How do I locate the right logfile it seems to have millions of those in the log folder

Comment: In IIS, right click website / manage website / advanced settings. See the field ID. It is a number. (Rant: Why MS dont show this on the logging settings for the website, sigh)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I exactly understand the question, but I'll have a stab.

If you've set up a virtual directory that includes the images, the chances are, that directory is at the root of the website. So, http://localhost/otherimages.

If this is the case, `Url.Content("~/otherimages/pic.jpg")` will not work as it is looking the the root of the web application (at http://localhost/myapp/otherimages). What it sounds like you need to do is something like:

```
Url.Content("/otherimages/pic.jpg")
```

This is basically removing the tilde "~" and forcing the `Url.Content()` to look at the website root, rather than the web application root.

Note: This means your app is reliant upon an external directory existing in a specific location with a specific name. If you're happy with that, then all is well :)

Comment: It doesn't work as a plain img tag doesn't work as well, can this be a permission/routing issue?

Comment: I'd imagine not if your images directory is a virtual directory. It sounds like, if you can't just type a URL in the browser, that there is an issue with the virtual directory setup. Can you confirm that the virtual directory is setup at the website root and called what you think it is?